# Mongoose - Append child documents to results that match a value

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections - `Assignments` and `Submissions` - where a teacher gives an assignment and all students can upload a submission. I want to query the db so that I'll retrieve all the assignments that have been posted, and for each one, tag on the student's submission (if it exists) that goes with it.

```
AssignmentSchema = new Schema({
    teacher: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
    course: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Course', required: true},
    name: {type: String},
    ...
});

SubmissionSchema = new Schema({
    assignment: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Assignment', required: true},
    student: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
    ...
});
```

Attempt using aggregation framework

```
Assignment.aggregate([
    {$match: {'course': new ObjectId(req.params.courseID)}},
    {$lookup: {
        from: 'submissions',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'assignment',
        as: 'submission'
    }},

    // Redact all submissions that aren't uploaded by the logged in user
    {$redact: {
        // This condition isn't working for some reason?
        $cond: {
            if: {
                $eq: ['$submission.user', new ObjectId(req.user._id)]
            },
            'then': '$$DESCEND',
            'else': '$$PRUNE' // Prune will remove the entire object. How can I only remove the assignments?
        }
    }},
    {$unwind: {
        path: '$submission',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }}
]);
```

The result that I need is this:

```
[{
    _id: '123456789',
    teacher: {teacher's id},
    course: '987654321',
    name: 'The assignment',
    submission: {
        assignment: '123456789',
        student: {authenticated user's id},
        ...
    },
    ...
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `$eq` expression with

`[{$ifNull: ["$user", new ObjectId(req.user._id)]}, new ObjectId(req.user._id)]`

`$redact` will go one document level at a time and look for `user` field recursively and perform `$$DESCEND` and `$$PRUNE` on the criteria.

Using `$ifNull` operator allows the `$redact` at the first document level, which doesn't have a `$user` field, to continue by comparing the replacement user id (`new ObjectId(req.user._id)`) value against `new ObjectId(req.user._id)`so that you can `$$DESCEND` to embedded document level for further processing.

Update:

`$project` with `$filter` seems more appropriate than `$redact`. Something like

```
{
    $project: {
    _id: 1,
    teacher: 1,
    course: 1,
    name: 1,
    submission: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$submission",
                as: "result",
                cond: {
                    $eq: ["$$result.user", new ObjectId(req.user._id)]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```